# Show all functions (e.g., print, summary) for a class (e.g., lm) in R

Tags: r

This is super silly but...how do I list all the functions for a particular class? E.g., for `lm` there is `print.lm`, `summary.lm`, `plot.lm` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```r
methods(class = "lm")
#>  [1] add1           alias          anova          case.names     coerce        
#>  [6] confint        cooks.distance deviance       dfbeta         dfbetas       
#> [11] drop1          dummy.coef     effects        extractAIC     family        
#> [16] formula        fortify        hatvalues      influence      initialize    
#> [21] kappa          labels         logLik         model.frame    model.matrix  
#> [26] nobs           plot           predict        print          proj          
#> [31] qqnorm         qr             residuals      rstandard      rstudent      
#> [36] show           simulate       slotsFromS3    summary        variable.names
#> [41] vcov          
#> see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also pass unquoted function names

```
methods(class = lm)
#[1] add1           alias          anova          case.names     coerce         confint        cooks.distance deviance      
#[9] dfbeta         dfbetas        drop1          dummy.coef     effects        extractAIC     family         formula       
#[17] hatvalues      influence      initialize     kappa          labels         logLik         model.frame    model.matrix  
#[25] nobs           plot           predict        print          proj           qr             residuals      rstandard     
#[33] rstudent       show           simulate       slotsFromS3    summary
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks to both of you. Why are these different results?

Comment: @user111024 where is it different.  I removed the `see '?methods'` part

Comment: ,e.g.,  yours is missing `fortify` at index [17]. But I see they are the same when I run `methods(class = lm)` and `methods(class = "lm")`